# Compatibility settings

Tags: c#, .net, properties, settings, compatibility

I'm working on a troubleshooting program, which will help users to fix certain errors caused by.. all sorts of things.

Anyway, one of the features I want it to have, is change a program's compatibility mode to windows XP mode without Visual Theme's. But I couldn't find anything.

So I'm just wondering if this is possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Application.EnableVisualStyles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, that's one down. :)

Comment: It is not :)  Can't stop that program from calling it.

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to stop the program from calling that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your program (.exe) and select Properties. Once properties dialog is open, look for Compatibility tab. Select it and check "Compatibility Mode" check box and select Windows XP from drop down list. That should run your .exe in Windows XP compatibility mode then. HTH

Comment: Yea, I could do it like that, but that's not really a feature. I guess it's called changing the properties programmatically.